# Проблема с инициализацией MapboxMap

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой, что при вызове метода рисования линий не из фрагмента с картой, карта выдаёт NullPointerException.

Код инициализации карты.

```
 mapView.getMapAsync (object: OnMapReadyCallback {
        override fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
            val bounds = LatLngBounds.Builder()
                    .include(LatLng(56.0431162,37.5329372)) // Northeast
                    .include(LatLng(55.4725803, 37.7006232))
                    .include(LatLng(55.6368534, 37.4429595))
                    .include(LatLng(55.7499363, 37.9918402))// Southwest
                    .build()
                mapboxMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(bounds)

            map = mapboxMap
            enableLocationPlugin()

            Log.e("map create", ""+ map)


        }
```

код метода

```
 map!!.addPolyline(
                    PolylineOptions()
                            .addAll(latLngs)
                            .color(Color.parseColor("#3bb2d0"))
                            .width(8F))
```

код ошибки.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.vendox.citytrack, PID: 12914
              kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                  at com.example.vendox.citytrack.Presentation.View.Map.MapFragment.drawPolyline(MapFragment.kt:335)
                  at com.example.vendox.citytrack.Data.Repository.GetRoute$getRoute$1.onResponse(GetRoute.kt:46)
                  at com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.MapboxDirections$1.onResponse(MapboxDirections.java:166)
                  at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6665)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

Comment: Ошибка здесь `com.example.vendox.citytrack.Presentation.View.Map.MapFragment.drawPolyline(MapFragment.kt:335)`, приведите код фрагмента.

Comment: это как раз map!!.addPolyline
но если вызывать метод из этого же фрагмента тогда всё хорошо

Comment: У вас `KotlinNullPointerException`, это значит что прилетает `null`, где не должен. Приведите сигнатуру метода.

Comment: Вот ссылка на код:
https://gist.github.com/vehdox/a9a093b51dfc0c763b3a60896ed9defe
Если всё кроме адаптера в один класс запихнуть - всё работает.

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю, в коде `MapPresenter().drawPolyline(...)` а в трейсе `MapFragment.drawPolyline(...)`. Где правда? Код с трейсом не стыкуется.

Comment: Так при коде который я скинул чуть выше,нет ошибки и ответ от сервера есть, но на карте ничего не тображается